# Listview with checkedtextview and when checkedtextview is checked listview expands and expanded view must also clickable

Tags: listview, expandablelistview, checkedtextview

Like here when checkedtextview is selected list expands and expanded view is also clickable to increment the item:

[image]

Comment: Where is your code? Have your written something. If no then I can just give you idea that. Instead of listview better use recyclerview to hold all the items. Now create one fragment to contain your increment operation. On click of recyclerview item you can show your fragment passing relevant data to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i am trying using Expandablelistview but cant get desired output .Can you please give me example of recyclerview with fragment ??

Comment: I need to write that code actually. Not having ready with me.

Comment: kk bro now i trying to do with recyclerview but checkedtextview not checking in recyclerview any idea how to solve dis??

Comment: Ok see in the below comment

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it happens with recycler view. Unlike list view, recyclerview doesn't which of its child has been clicked on so you can not implement anything like recyclerView.OnItemClickListerner. Instead what you need to do, you need to implement the onClickListener (OnCheckedListener in your case) in your adapter and then pass that flow to your activity (if you need else you can process it inside adapter as well).

**Now being more specific to your scenario:**

**Java files:**

1. Activity holding recyclerview
2. Adapter holding drawing of childs and binding with data. Implements OnCheckedChange listener (or whatever you need).
3. Fragment having increment operation

**XML files**
 1. main.xml for activity having recyclerview
 2. item.xml which will have checkbox, textview for title, textview for price, framelayout in invisible state.
3. Two imageview for left right arrow and one textview.

**Flow**

1. Get all data from server on your activity
2. Pass it to adapter so adapter will be having all the datas available
3. When user checks the box--> adapter's checkedChangeListener method will be called and then you would be adding fragment to your framelayout and make it visible.

This would be the logic to implement this. Please try this way and you would be able to achieve it. All the best :)

Comment: kk i will try this :)